# How to convert a light switch to always on

Tags: switch

I have a switch that turns on/off two lamps in the driveway. I want to remove the switch and make the lamps always on, since I’ve installed smart bulbs on them and I don’t want anyone to turn off that switch. The switch only have two wires and the ground. So to me, it was as simple as putting those two wires together with a wire nut. I did that and when I turned the breaker back on, it exploded and the breaker tripped. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Which two wires did you put together?

Comment: Are you sure you did not let that bear copper wire touch the hot on the other switch? Connecting the 2 insulated wires that were on the switch together with a wirenut was the right thing to do, however that bare copper on the green screw could have shorted the hot on the other switch.

Comment: Does sound like ground touch/connected with a hot wire/screw.  Plain switches just break a hot wire circuit.  Probably the number one reason for breaker tripping when working on a switch, bare ground touches hot when putting switch back in.

Comment: Yeah, that ground went somewhere it shouldn't have. Coil it up and push it into the back of the box. Also consider using a Decora blanking plate instead of putting the switch back on.

Comment: You all were right. It seems the ground touched one of the wires where it was a little stripped. Connected back the two black wires, made sure ground was not touching anything and, voila! It worked. Thanks you all for the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the switch worked, the wire on the green screw does not connect to anything or it can be attached to the box. The two (black) wires on the switch should be connected together. Then get a new plate and you are all set.